# A Problem of Inscribed Equilateral 2-Polyline

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, curves, convex-geometry

Given a regular strictly convex closed curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2,\ \gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$, prove or disprove that one can find three points $A, B, C\in\gamma$ such that $AB=BC$ and the area cut off by the chord $AB$ is equal to the area cut off by the chord $BC$ and they both are equal to the area between the chords (as it is depicted below).
I tried my best using twice Cauchy's intermediate value theorem, but does it really that easy? How can I prove or disprove the statement?

[image: The sketch.]

Comment: Why complicated word "polyline" in your title ?

Comment: This property doesn't look true even for a triangle.

Comment: @JeanMarie I used the word polyline because it is factually user in the task

Comment: For you, is "regular" meaning : "possessing a $C^1$ parameterization" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie actually, triangle is not a regular curve. :^) However, of course, you can 'smoothify' and make your triangle strictly convex with minute oscillations and the property still won't be true (if you can prove so). But probably thé fluctuations play the most important role in the problem. You provided no mathematical reasoning. I need an actual example with a disproof! :)

Comment: @JeanMarie "Regular" means no cusps. $C^1$ parametrization +  nowhere vanishing derivative

Answer (score 2):

The answer is YES. For such a regular convex closed curve, one can always find $A,B,C$ on it with $|AB| = |BC|$ and split the region it bounded into 3 sub-regions with equal areas.

The key is if one pick a point $E$ on the curve and locate another point $F$ to make chord $EF$ to cut out a fixed amount of area from the region, the $F$ so constructed depends on $E$ continuously.

Once one has that, the rest will be a simple application of IVT.
The real issue is how to justify $F$ depends on $E$ continuously.
Following is my clumsy attempt.

---

Given a convex body $K$ whose boundary $\partial K$ admits a $C^1$ parametrization with nonwhere vanishing derivatives.
Let $P, D$ and $\Delta$ be its perimeter, diameter and area.
Reparametrize $\partial K$ by arc length:
$$\gamma: [0,P] \ni s \mapsto \gamma(s) \in \partial K$$
Since $\partial K$ has at least one $C^1$ parametrization, $\gamma$ is also $C^1$. The condition of nowhere vanishing derivatives implies the tangent vector
$$\frac{d\gamma}{ds} = \left(\frac{dx}{ds},\frac{dy}{ds}\right) = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$$
is well defined and continuous. Up to modulo $2\pi$, so does the angle $\theta$.
WOLOG, we will assume orientation of $\gamma$ is positive. Since $K$ is convex, this means $\theta(s)$ is locally non-decreasing.  Extend parameterization $\gamma$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ by
periodicity. The corresponding $\theta(s)$ can be lifted to a continuous non-decreasing function over $\mathbb{R}$.

For any $p = (p_1,p_2), q = (q_1,q_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $[p,q] = \frac12(p_1 q_2 - p_2q_1)$. When $p \ne q$, the pair $p, q$ defined an oriented line ($p \to q$). Let $H_{pq}$ be the closed half-plane consists of points on RHS of this line:

$$H_{pq} = \{ u \in \mathbb{R}^2, [ q-p, u ] \le 0 \}$$

For any $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in (s, s + P)$, let
$$K_{st} = K \cap H_{\gamma(s)\gamma(t)}
\quad\text{ and }\quad A(s,t) = \verb/Area/(K_{st})$$

Since $K_{st}$ is convex compact, $A(s,t)$ is supremum of area of all polygon inscribed within it. Since $\gamma$ is $C^1$, we can approximate $\gamma$ by a sequence of polylines, the convex hull of these polylines with $\gamma(s)$ allow us to generate a sequence of inscribed polygons which converges to $K_{st}$ (with respect to Hausdorff metric among convex bodies). We can evaluate the area of those inscribed polygons by shoelace formula. By passing to the limit, we obtain following formula for $A(s,t)$.

$$A(s,t) = \int_s^t [ \gamma(\tau) - \gamma(s), \gamma'(\tau) ] d\tau =
\int_s^t [ \gamma(\tau),\gamma'(\tau) ] d\tau - [\gamma(s),\gamma(t)]
$$
Since $\gamma$ is $C^1$, this formula tell us $A(s,t)$ is $C^1$ in both variables $s$ and $t$.

Since $K$ is convex, for $t_1, t_2 \in (s,s+L)$ with $t_1 < t_2$, we have
$$K_{st_1} \subset K_{st_2}\quad\implies\quad 
A(s,t_1) \le A(s,t_2)$$
This means $A(s,t)$ is non-decreasing in $t$.

In fact, we have a stronger result. For those $t$ where $A(s,t) \ne 0$ nor $\Delta$, we have
$$\partial_t A(s,t) \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{\partial A(s,t)}{\partial t} = [\gamma(t)-\gamma(s),\gamma'(t)]
= \frac12|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)|\sin(\theta(s) - \phi)$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between $\gamma(t) - \gamma(s)$ and $x$-axis.
It is clear $|\gamma(t) - \gamma(s)| \ne 0$. Furthermore, $\sin(\theta(s) - \phi) \ne 0$ cannot vanish. Otherwise, the tangent line of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t)$ will pass through $\gamma(s)$ and convexity of $K$ will lead to a contraction that $A(s,t)$ equals to either $0$ or $\Delta$.
Together with $A(s,t)$ is non-increasing in $t$, this leads to
$$A(s,t) \in (0,\Delta) \implies \partial_t A(s,t) > 0$$
From this, we can deduce there are $s \le t_a < t_b \le s + P$ such that
$$A(s,t)
\begin{cases}
= 0, & t \in (s,t_a]\\
\text{ strictly increasing }, & t \in (t_a,t_b)\\
= \Delta, & t \in [t_b,s+L)
\end{cases}$$

Notice for $t \in (s,s+\epsilon)$, we have the bound
$A(s,t) \le \pi \epsilon^2$. this means $A(s,t) \to 0$ as $t \to s+$.
By a similar argument, $A(s,t) \to \Delta$ as $t \to (s+L)-$.
By continuity of $A(s,t)$ in $t$, for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$, there exists $t \in (s,s+L)$ such that $A(s,t) = \lambda \Delta$. By above "increasing property" in $t$, we find such a $t$ is unique.
Let's call this $t$ as $q_\lambda(s)$.

For any fixed $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $s_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, let $t_0 = q_\lambda(s_0)$.

Consider the graph in $\left\{ (s,t) \in \mathbb{R^2} : t - s \in (0,L) \right\}$ defined by an implicit equation:

$$F(s,t) \stackrel{def}{=} A(s,t) - \lambda \Delta = 0$$

This graph is non-empty as $(s_0,t_0)$ belongs to it. It is $C^1$ in both
$s$ and $t$. Finally, $\partial_t F(s,t) = \partial_t A(s,t)$ is non-zero at $(s,t) = (s_0,t_0)$. By [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), there is a  neighborhood $U = (s_0-\epsilon,s_0+\epsilon)$ of $s_0$ and a unique $C^1$ function $g : U \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(s_0) = t_0$ and solves $F(s,g(s)) = 0$ on $U$.

Since $q_\lambda(s)$ satisfies last two conditions on $U$. It coincides with $g$ there. This means $q_\lambda(s)$ is $C^1$ over some neighborhood of $s_0$. Since $s_0$ can be arbitrary, $q_\lambda(s)$ is $C^1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

By a similar construction for $t \in (s-L,s)$, we obtain the main lemma we need:

> For any $\lambda \in (0,1)$, there exists two $C^1$ functions $p_\lambda$, $q_\lambda$ which are inverse to each other,
> satisfy $s - P < p_\lambda(s) < s < q_\lambda(s) < s + P$ and
> $$A(p_\lambda(s),s) = A(s,q_\lambda(s)) = \lambda \Delta$$

Let $\ell_p(s) = |\gamma(p_\lambda(s)) - \gamma(s)|$ and $\ell_q(s) = |\gamma(s) - \gamma(q_\lambda(s))|$. They are $C^1$ functions with period $P$. So $\ell_q(s)$ reaches absolute minimum at some $s_*$. Let $t_* = q_\lambda(s_*)$. Notice
$$\begin{align}
\ell_p(s_*) - \ell_q(s_*) &= \ell_q(p_\lambda(s_*)) - \ell_q(s_*) \ge 0\\
\ell_p(t_*) - \ell_q(t_*) &= \ell_q(s_*) - \ell_q(t_*) \le 0
\end{align}$$
The $C^1$ function $\ell_p(s) - \ell_q(s)$ changes sign over $(s_*,t_*)$.
By IVT, there is a $s^\dagger \in (s_*,t_*)$ such that
$$\ell_p(s^\dagger) = \ell_q(s^\dagger)
\quad\iff\quad
|\gamma(p_\lambda(s^\dagger)) - \gamma(s^\dagger)| = |\gamma(q_\lambda(s^\dagger)) - \gamma(s^\dagger)|
$$

Back to original problem, take $\lambda = \frac13$ and $\Delta = 3S$,
the three points $\gamma(q_\lambda(s^\dagger)), \gamma(s^\dagger), \gamma(p_\lambda(s^\dagger)$ will be the $A, B, C$ one need for the chords.